# Where can I get the source code for Linux?

Tags: c, linux

Where can I get the source code for Linux and not one of its distros? And what languages do I have to learn to understand the system other than C?

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://distrowatch.com/table-mobile.php?distribution=lfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux `5.13` (latest as of July 2021) source code is located at https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.13.tar.xz. You can download it and extract it with those commands:

```
wget "https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.13.tar.xz"
tar xvf linux-5.13.tar.xz
```

Also, Linux has official Github repository at [torvalds/linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) and official git server is located at https://git.kernel.org/, can be downloaded with `git`:

```
git clone "https://github.com/torvalds/linux"
```

Besides C, you should learn GNU Makefile, a bit of Assembly language, and shell scripting. Github has a `Languages` section with technologies used in project visualized:
[image]

As you can see, it's mostly C.

Answer (score 1):

Linux (the kernel) can be found at https://www.kernel.org/

Most of it is written in C with some assembly etc